# How to remove 'Assignment of Parameter 'variable' is not allowed'

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm programming a Controller using Java and I'm checking the style using Sonar. In my Sonar I have an error that says:

> 'Assignment of Parameter 'variable' is not allowed.

The line that it's on is:

```
@RequestParam(value="variable", required=false) String variable
```

So I'm wondering how I could get that error off since I can't just create a setter when I'm using that annotation.

### EDIT

I'm using `Eclipse`. The rule being broke is `Parameter Assignment`.

```
@RequestParam(value="variable", required=false) String variable
if (variable != null && variable.compareTo("") == 0) {
    variable = null;
}
```

Comment: Can we see more context? Aka more code?

Comment: are you using eclipse?

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: Can you post which rule is raising the issue ? (rule key)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your if condition block, you are setting ***variable*** to null and it happens to be your method parameter. Instead of assigning the value to the method parameter, create a local variable and use it and return the value of the local variable from the method if at all it is intended.